# Datetime Module, Time

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print the actual time on an hourly based automated Email, but the program is repeating the first printed time again again. For Example, if the first rounds starts at 6:00 AM cst,again in the next email it is printing the same instead of 7:00, where I'm going wrong with the code below

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
import time
utc = timezone('UTC')
central = pytz.timezone('US/Central')
today = datetime.now(central)
crntDte = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
crntTime = datetime.now(central).strftime('%H:%M')

def Action():
print('Process started at '+ crntDte + " " + crntTime)

schedule.every(2).minutes.do(Action)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending() 
    time.sleep(1)
```

crntDte is working fine, but crnTime is printing the sametime everyhour

Answer (score 0):

Well, your timezone looks not properly set. There are two `timezone` that are from `pytz` and `datetime`. I think you have to specify which one you will use.

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
import time

central  = pytz.timezone('US/Central')
today    = datetime.now(central)
crntDte  = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
crntTime = today.strftime('%H:%M')

print('Process started at '+ crntDte + " " + crntTime)
```

The result is then (for now)

```
Process started at 10/19/2019 09:18
```

---

When you do some schedule, then you have to re-calculate the time. So, your action should have all the definitions not only the print statement.

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
import time

def Action():
    central  = pytz.timezone('US/Central')
    today    = datetime.now(central)
    crntDte  = today.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    crntTime = today.strftime('%H:%M')
    print('Process started at '+ crntDte + " " + crntTime)

schedule.every(2).minutes.do(Action)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending() 
    time.sleep(1)
```

There are not updated automatically.

Comment: Hi, I've tried your suggestions but still the script prints the same time every 2 mins, I've made an edit to the code.

Comment: You have to call the `datetime.now()` everytime when you do action.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your help )